# Django: Want to display an empty field as blank rather displaying None

Tags: python, django, null

I have a template called client_details.html that displays `user`, `note` and `datetime`. Now sometimes, a client may not have an entry for user, note and datetime. What my program will do instead is display `None` if these fields are empty. I do not want the to display None. If a field has no value I don't want to see any value e.g. let it be blank if possible instead of displaying None.

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def get_client(request, client_id = 0):
    client = None
    try:
        client = models.Client.objects.get(pk = client_id)
    except:
        pass
    return render_to_response('client_details.html', {'client':client}, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

**template**

```
{{client.datetime}}<br/> 
{{client.datetime.time}}<br/>  
{{client.user}}<br/>
{{client.note}}<br/>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you may use:

```
{% if client %} {{client.user}} {% else %} &nbsp; {% endif %}
```

Checking with an **if** is enough, so you may not user else block if you want...

Comment: This is not working for integers with no value.

Answer (score 145):

Use the built-in [`default_if_none`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#default-if-none) filter.

```
{{ client.user|default_if_none:"&nbsp;" }}
{{ client.user|default_if_none:"" }}
```

Comment: There's also the `default` filter, but `default_if_none` is more specific. If you're dealing with model instances for these things though then it'll all come to the same thing.

Comment: this should be selected answer

Answer (score 7):

this is such a strange problem.
I have a good idea for it. If you want to modify your field at display time than rather checking it at template , check it at your model class.

```
ExampleModel(models.Model):
    myfield = models.CharField(blank=True, null = True)

    @property
    def get_myfield(self)
        if self.myfield:
              return self.myfield
        else:
              return ""
```

Use it in your template directly instead of field.

```
 {{ExampleModel.get_myfield}}
```

you never need to change your template to change this field in future, just modify you property.