# How not to display a field when it's None in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I have this model:

```
class MsTune(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255) # title (source)
    start_page = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True, default=None)

def __str__(self):
        if not self.start_page or self.start_page != '' or self.start_page is not None or self.start_page is not "None" or self.start_page is not null:
            return '%s, %s' % (self.name, self.start_page)
        else:
            return '%s' % (self.name)
```

As you can see, I want only `name` if `start_page` is empty, or `name, start_page` if `start_page` is filled. No matter how many conditions I put (see above), I keep getting `name, None` in my template. What am I missing? Also, is there a shorter code I can put in place, instead of the verbose `if / else` ?

**Edit**

This is the content of my field in the database:

```
mysql> SELECT start_page from bassculture_mstune where id = 1942;
+------------+
| start_page |
+------------+
| NULL       |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

And in Django's shell:

```
>>> mytune = MsTune.objects.get(id=1942)
>>> print(mytune.start_page)
None
```

Comment: 2nd answer on  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6584235/django-want-to-display-an-empty-field-as-blank-rather-displaying-none  uses the built-in default_if_none filter.

Comment: what do you get, when using positive condition? 
if self.start_page: return '%s, %s' % (self.name, self.start_page)  else: return '%s' % (self.name)   In fact, it'd more enlightening to show view and template.

Comment: The view is a simple `tunes = MsTune.objects.all()`, and the template just `{% for tune in tunes %} {{ tune }}{% endfor %}`. The positive condition shows the string "title, None" to the template.

Comment: I think the if statement is not as you want to have it ... "or" is the wrong logic. It should be something like ... is not "None" and ... is not "Null" ... etc.

Comment: Nope, I'm still getting None. Besides, why 'and'? It'll never bee all those things together.

Comment: If it is "None" it is not "" ... so the other "or" condition is true and it displays the  None

Comment: Well, I put all 'and's and it's still outputting None unfortunately.

Comment: Also remove "Not self.start_page" at the beginning

Comment: No luck, I'm afraid. I still think that the 'and' is not right, since returns true only if all conditions are true, while I want to test if either is null, or empty, or none, when only one of them is true I don't want to output start_page. Anyway, with all 'and's and not 'not start_page' is still returning None.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As default value is going to be `""` as from your field, simply checking not `value` should work:

```
def __str__(self):
    returnVal = f"{self.name}"
    if self.start_page:
        returnVal = f"{returnVal}, {self.start_page}"
    return returnVal
```

Or, you can use ternery operation:

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.start_page and f"{self.name}, {self.start_page}" or f"{self.name}"
```

Python ternary operation: [Refs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14461984/10860596)

Comment: As you can see from my code above, I already have the `if self.start_page is not None` condition. My main problem is that `None` is still displayed.

Comment: @HBMCS edditted, have a look.

Comment: That's also what I tried as first thing. I've added it to the loooong list of 'ifs'. Still no luck. Can it be how the data has been written in the MySQL database? I've imported it from a .sql dump. What other kind of null/None/'none' can there be?

Comment: @HBMCS can you try: `print(self.start_page)` and check what is the output. Both in template and in terminal/